# JavaScript - regex that matches in any order

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following regex that returns keyword values:

```
 var keywords = result.match(/<meta name="keywords" content="(.*?)".*/i)[1];
```

I also need to be able to support situations where the "keywords" and the "content" properties  are in the reverse order e.g:

```
<meta content="...." name="keywords"
```

Can anyone advise how I can support both orders?

Comment: If that regex works, I wouldn't try to over-complicate things, just use another one with name and content reversed and then check which one returned values.

Comment: Can't you just target the given `meta[name=keyword]` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookahead to check first that the `name="keywords"` exists, then parse `content`.

```
var keywords = result.match(/<meta(?=[^>]*\bname="keywords")[^>]*\bcontent="(.*?)".*/i)[1];
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can `""` contain `>` character? I don't know much about htmls. But that case it will not work.

Comment: Yes, attributes can contain `>`, this is one of the many reasons why the pony comes ;)

Answer (score 1):

[**THE PONY HE COMES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

With access to the DOM at your fingertips, you have no excuse not to dump your HTML into a temporary document (or, if it's the current document, work on it from there). Then, depending on browser version, you can just `querySelector("meta[name=keywords]")` or iterate through `getElementsByTagName('meta')` until you find the right one, before using `getAttribute("content")` to get the result.